# Why is this function type "ill-typed"

Tags: types, functional-programming, set, ocaml

Given a set interface with `val add : ’a -> ’a set -> ’a set`, why is it that inputting `add 3 [1]` doesn't type check? I thought its type would be `int set`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `[1]` has the type `int list`, not `int set`. If you show more of the Set interface we might be able to help more.

Often a set interface has `Set.empty` and `Set.singleton`. So your example could perhaps be coded as `add 3 (singleton 1)` or as `add 3 (add 1 empty)`

Comment: The module mentions :`val empty : ’a set` and
`val is_empty : ’a set -> bool`. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: `empty: 'a set`: yes, that is what I mean by `empty` in my example. `is_empty` is something else--it's a function that tells whether a set is empty.